# FTP Server vsftpd change ftp:nogroup

Tags: linux, debian, ftp

I'm running vsftpd using the Debian Lenny package. `ftp:nogroup` is the user/group that uploads files and owns uploaded files. However, a problem is arising - another process is also writing files to the FTP directory as `myprocess:mygroup` with restrictive file permissions, preventing vsftpd from overwriting the `myprocess` authored files.  Is it possible to tell vsftpd to use a different user/group for uploading files? (preferably as `myprocess:mygroup` or `ftp:mygroup`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your vsftpd.conf:

```
 chown_uploads=YES
 chown_username=ftp
 chown_upload_mode=640
```

For the group, use the set-user-ID bit on the incoming directory (`chgrp mygroup incoming && chmod g+s incoming/`)